# kotlin unit test doesn't go through the function

Tags: kotlin

I have a getQueueUrl function, which used to get url from sqs, when I pass the invalid value into that fucntion, this test suppose to fail because the actual exception I throw is wrong(InvalidRequestException), but the test still pass and didn't print the message I put in that function, why does this happened?

```
class SqsUtil {
    @Throws(QueueDoesNotExistException::class)
    fun getQueueUrl(amazonSQS: AmazonSQS, queueName: String): String {
        try {
            print("defew" + amazonSQS.getQueueUrl((queueName)).queueUrl)
            return amazonSQS.getQueueUrl((queueName)).queueUrl
        } catch (e: QueueDoesNotExistException) {
            logger.error("Unable to connect to SQS: {}, Exception: {}", queueName, e)
            throw QueueDoesNotExistException("Unable to connect to SQS: $queueName")
        }
    }

}
```

```
 @Mock
    private lateinit var sqs: AmazonSQS

@BeforeEach
    fun setup() {
        sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard()
            .withRegion("us-west-2").build()
    }

private var sqsUtil = Mockito.mock(SqsUtil::class.java)

@Test
    fun `Get queue url throws exception`() {

        `when`(sqsUtil.getQueueUrl(sqs, "test")).thenThrow(InvalidRequestException::class.java)
    }
```

Comment: Did you intend to mock out the class you are testing? `when` is configuring a mock sqsUtil, not calling your code.

Comment: @roby, i'm not to mock out the class you are testing, how can I change the code?

Comment: `val sqsUtil = SqsUtil()`. Then I imagine you wanted to use that `when` code to set up the mock `sqs` and then call `sqsUtil.getQueueUrl(sqs, "test")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test what I think you want to test.

First, it's unclear from your snippet if you have the test configured to inject the `@Mock` AmazonSQS variable.

Add a dependency on `org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.11.0` (or whatever your matching mockito version is). Then annotate your test class with `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)`. [MockitoExtension](https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter/3.11.0/org/mockito/junit/jupiter/MockitoExtension.html) extends Junit to create and inject Mocks into the test class based on the annotations.

Then you can delete your `@BeforeEach` method, as junit is taking care of creating the mock `sqs` field.

Next, you are mocking the class I think you want to test when you call `private var sqsUtil = Mockito.mock(SqsUtil::class.java)`. Instead you can instantiate your class with `private val sqsUtil = SqsUtil()`. I'm not entirely sure how your code is working, when I try Mockito cannot mock the kotlin class because it's final.

Then you use `when` to set up the mock `sqs` to throw the error you want. Like

```kotlin
`when`(sqs.getQueueUrl("test")).thenThrow(QueueDoesNotExistException::class.java)
```

and you can check SqsUtil re-throws the exception with:

```kotlin
assertThrows(QueueDoesNotExistException::class.java) {
    sqsUtil.getQueueUrl(sqs, "test")
}
```

All together my test class looks like this:

```kotlin
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith
import org.mockito.Mock
import org.mockito.Mockito.`when`
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension::class)
internal class SqsUtilTestCase {

    @Mock
    private lateinit var sqs: AmazonSQS

    private val sqsUtil =  SqsUtil()

    @Test
    fun `Get queue url throws exception`() {
        `when`(sqs.getQueueUrl("test")).thenThrow(QueueDoesNotExistException::class.java)
        assertThrows(QueueDoesNotExistException::class.java) {
            sqsUtil.getQueueUrl(sqs, "test")
        }
    }
}
```

To get around issues with mockito and kotlin not playing together nicely I can recommend [mockk](https://mockk.io). With a dependency on `io.mockk:mockk:1.11.0` here's how the test looks.

```kotlin
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.QueueDoesNotExistException
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test

internal class SqsUtilTestCase {

    private val sqs: AmazonSQS = mockk()

    private val sqsUtil = SqsUtil()

    @Test
    fun `Get queue url throws exception`() {
        every { sqs.getQueueUrl("test") }.throws(QueueDoesNotExistException("fail"))
        assertThrows(QueueDoesNotExistException::class.java) {
            sqsUtil.getQueueUrl(sqs, "test")
        }
    }
}
```